# Amazon S3 sporadic "access is denied" errors on https

Tags: https, amazon-s3, access-denied

Some of our users have problems to load the .js and .css hosted on S3. We track the JS errors on the server through window.onerror.
In the logs I can quite often see that for some users S3 that loading the .js produce an "Access is denied".

We use the bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/folder/file.js syntax.

What can we do about it? Is it an Amazon's problem?

Comment: See also https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=425976
The number of errors seems that is going down in the last hour.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set up a policy on S3 that includes the Effect:Allow element description for all principals using the GetObject action on your bucket.  You can generate policies for S3 (among others) here: http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html.

Comment: I am not sure why I should change the policy. That bucket is supposed to be open to everybody and it works for "almost" everybody.